# ios UITableView reloadData don't increase content height

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios6

I'm facing a strange error in my iOS app and haven't been able to figure out the reason why.

In my UITableView i can add new cells, so i refresh the array that is the datasource and call `reloadData`.

Everything works without error. The `numberOfRowsInSection` is called again, and it's value is one more than it's previous value was. The new cell even gets inserted at the bottom of the tableview, but i cant scroll down to it. I only know that it's there because the tableview bounces and i can see it.

I'm guessing the tableview's content height is not getting increased for some reason, but i have no idea why.

I'm using iOS 6 btw.

Any help is very much appreciated!
Thanks,

Zoli

EDIT, answers for Srikanth's questions:

1. How is data getting added.

There's an NSArray containing objects of a specific type. The array.count is the number of the number of cells. This NSArray gets its values from a database query.

1. When you say, you are refreshing the array, what do you mean.

By refreshing the array i mean i execute a new query in the database and put the results of this query into an NSArray. this will be the tableview's datasource array. Like this:

```
dataSourceArray = [dbManager executeQuery];
[tableView reloadData];
```

1. Are you adding the data within the same view controller

Yes.

1. Can you show some code as to what you are doing

See above.

1. Is the table view at the root of the view controllers view or is it within another view

The tableview is the main view's first child.

1. Can you try adding data to the array at the beginning, so that you can view the cell being added at the top.

I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: 1. How is data getting added. 2. When you say, you are refreshing the array, what do you mean.  3. Are you adding the data within the same view controller  4. Can you show some code as to what you are doing 5. Is the table view at the root of the view controllers view or is it within another view 6. Can you try adding data to the array at the beginning, so that you can view the cell being added at the top.

Comment: edited, check the new description

Comment: I would try with a simple array of data, manually populating it with strings where array starts out with A,B,C strings and then  add to the array and check if the problem is with any layout or UIKit issues or with some thing else. Is it an iPad Popover or a tableview added as a subview. How are you triggering the dbManager query execution. It is quite possible that your scrolling is causing the data to change by calling some method. Is there other pieces of the code which you can show.

Comment: I'm not sure about your [dbManager executeQuery]. Maybe it is asynchronous? So if the you call reloadData there is maybe not everything in place...

Comment: it's not my first tableview population with data, so i don't think adding strings would really help. I always populate the source array in the init function, so by the time tableview gets visible, the results are already in the array

Comment: Try adding `[self.tableView beginUpdates];` before your `[tableView reloadData];` and `[self.tableView endUpdates];` directly after. Maybe that does the trick?

Answer (score 0):

Check your tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: method. This method is probably somehow returning zero for the newly added row.

Comment: - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 78;
}  it's returning a constant

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to make sure i fetched the new content from the database before the tableview's reloaddata is called. for some reason the new content was in the tableview, but its content height was smaller. My guess is the numberOfRowsInSection was called before the new result was in the array, but its content was coming from the array with the new data. But that doesn't make sense either...

But making sure with a callback that reloading the tableview came only after the fetch query was finished solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue, and the only way I was able to make it behave right was not to use reloadData, but to reload all sections (which comes down to the same thing, but obviously not when it comes to internal UITableView contentSize recalculation).

Anyway, when your model is loaded, don't do [ self.myTableView reloadData ], call this instead:

```
-(void)reloadDataWithAnimation {
    [self.myTableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, self.myTableView.numberOfSections)] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
}
```

Animation is not necessary, I just needed it to look that way.